# CodeIgniter Include of Vzaar Library

Tags: php, codeigniter, include

I am trying to load the Vzaar libraries into Codeigniter. Should these file go into the libraries directory. If so there are multiple files, which one would I make the call to from my controller. I believe the main library file is `Vzaar.php`. Therefore should my call be

```
$this->load->libraries('Vzaar');
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this library is a standard PHP class called Vzaar? If so, then yes, what you've said is correct. Put Vzaar.php into your application/libraries folder and load it up at any time using $this->load->libraries('Vzaar'). Then you can use it by doing $this->Vzaar->myFunction(). For more info, check out CI's awesome user guide:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, *$this->load->libraries('Vzaar')* followed by *$this->Vzaar::function_name()* should do the job, since it's just a PHP class and it has all require_once instructions inside of it already.

Evi Skitsanos, 
vzaar API Head of Support, 
email: evi@vzaar.com | twitter: http://twitter.com/skitsanos